# Filter dataframe based on one pattern that is conditional on another pattern

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

Can't seem to wrap my head around a seemingly simple task: how to filter a dataframe based on a pattern in one column, **which, however, is to match only if** a pattern in another column matches:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Speaker = c("A", NA, "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"),
  Utterance = c("uh-huh",                       
                "(0.666)",                     
                "WOW!",                        
                "#yeah#",               
                "=right=",             
                "oka::y¿",               
                "okay",                   
                "some stuff",             
                "!more! £TAlk£"),        
  Orthographic = c("uh-huh", "NA", "wow", "yeah", "right", "okay", "okay", "some stuff", "more talk")
)
```

I want to remove rows in `df` where the pattern `^(yeah|okay|right|mhm|mm|uh(-| )?huh)$` matches in column `Orthographic` **but not** if these rows contain any character from character class `[A-Z:↑↓£#¿?!]` in column `Utterance`.

**Expected outcome**:

```
df
  Speaker     Utterance Orthographic
3       B          WOW!          wow
4       C        #yeah#         yeah
6       B       oka::y¿         okay
8       B    some stuff   some stuff
9       C !more! £TAlk£    more talk
```

**Attempts so far**: (filters too much!)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(Speaker)) %>%      
  filter(!grepl("^(yeah|okay|right|mhm|mm|uh(-| )?huh)$", Orthographic) 
         & grepl("[A-Z:↑↓£#¿?!]", Utterance))
  Speaker     Utterance Orthographic
1       B          WOW!          wow
2       C !more! £TAlk£    more talk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `|` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(Speaker)) %>%
  filter(!grepl("^(yeah|okay|right|mhm|mm|uh(-| )?huh)$", Orthographic) 
         | grepl("[A-Z:↑↓£#¿?!]", Utterance))

#  Speaker     Utterance Orthographic
#1       B          WOW!          wow
#2       C        #yeah#         yeah
#3       B       oka::y¿         okay
#4       B    some stuff   some stuff
#5       C !more! £TAlk£    more talk
```

Keep rows that does not have `^(yeah|okay|right|mhm|mm|uh(-| )?huh)$` Or have `[A-Z:↑↓£#¿?!]`.

Comment: Yes, of course, that does it! I could have sworn I've tried that too, but apparently I haven't ! ;)